# Localization of view without using @Localizer

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, localization, globalization

I am using localization for view as given below.

```
<p>@Localizer["Use this area to provide additional information."]</p
```

I need to create a global resource file from where I can localize the string of view without using ViewModels folder in resource folder.

```
Resources/ViewModels/Account/RegisterViewModel.fr.resx
```

Is there any way to use localization of view without using IViewLocalizer or without using @Localizer in view?

Answer (score 0):

here is how to do it :
on your resx file properties, add "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" for Custom tool.
It will generate the "designer file".
You need to do it only for main language file.
After that, on your view in cshtml, you can use it like this :

```
//my resource file is named Welcome.resx    
<h1>@Welcome.Title</h1>
```

[image]